# PyQt5 - QSlider in real time

Tags: python, pyqt5, intervals, qmediaplayer, qslider

I'm creating a software to read and process videos. I just began this project but I already have an issue. I want to create a slider which reacts in real time. Currently, the slider only moves around very seconds.
My slider is set up like that.

```
    self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
    self.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.set_position)
    
    def set_position(self, position):
       self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)
```

I tried to use ***setTickPosition(QSlider::TickPosition position)*** but it doesn't change anything. Maybe I'm not using the good function.

Maybe this code could help you to see where I stuck

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QSlider, QHBoxLayout, QStyle, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Slider tick settings")
        self.setGeometry(350, 100, 720, 700)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))

        self.init_ui()
        
        self.show()
        
    def init_ui(self):
        
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        
        VideoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.set_position)
        
        self.playBtn = QPushButton("Play")
        self.openFile = QPushButton("Open File")
        self.playBtn.clicked.connect(self.play_video)
        self.openFile.clicked.connect(self.open_file)
        
        self.qhbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.qvbox = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.qhbox.addWidget(self.slider)
        self.qhbox.addWidget(self.openFile)
        self.qhbox.addWidget(self.playBtn)
        self.qvbox.addLayout(self.qhbox) 
        self.qvbox.addWidget(VideoWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.qvbox)
    
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(VideoWidget)
        
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediastate_changed)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.position_changed)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.duration_changed)
        
    def set_position(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)
    
    def mediastate_changed(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playBtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playBtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
    
    def open_file(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Video")
        if filename != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)))
            self.playBtn.setEnabled(True)
            #self.getRealFilename(filename)
            
    def position_changed(self, position):
        self.slider.setValue(position)
        
    def duration_changed(self, duration):
        self.slider.setRange(0, duration)
        
    def set_position(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)
         
    def play_video(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState :
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else :
            self.mediaPlayer.play()       
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `setTickPosition` sets how the ticks (the small lines on the sides of the slider) are displayed. That said, please provide a [mre]

Comment: I updated my post with my full code

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work just fine. Please consider that some video formats don't support precise seeking due to their implementation, so it's possible that you can only access the "keyframes" and not the exact point you're trying to seek. Unfortunately, with the current implementation of QMediaPlayer, there's no workaround.

Comment: Ok I think I expressed myself badly... I'm not trying to navigate by clicking on the slider. I would like the slider to follow the rhythm of the video in a fluid way and not jerky every ~1 second

Comment: note that you defined `set_position` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ticks have nothing to do with that, nor the slider.

The problem is the default interval that QMediaPlayer uses for notifications, which is 1000ms.

If you want to change that, use [`setNotifyInterval()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaobject.html#notifyInterval-prop) with a *proper* millisecond interval (I suggest to not use values smaller than 100-150ms).